# Add or update dictionary key value pair item in an array of a document in an atomic operation

Tags: c#, mongodb, atomic

Given the following document:

```
  {
"_id": ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
"myarray": [
  {
    "key": 1
    "mydictionary":
    {
      "PointA": {
        userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
        point: 5
      },
      "PointB":{
        userId: ObjectId("613ca5e48dbe673802c2d522"),
        point: 2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 2
    "mydictionary":
    {
      "PointA": {
        userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
        point: 5
      },
      "PointB":{
        userId: ObjectId("613ca5e48dbe673802c2d522"),
        point: 2
      }
    }
  }
]
```

}

What I need is to add or update a new point (based on key name, for example "Point A" would be updated but a new item "Point C" should be added) in an atomic operation. And also by the specific array's item key.

What I've been trying so far is to first transform the dictionary to a normal array and try to make it work like that. This is the update. Just trying to merge or to concat the array depending if the item already exists or not.

```
        db.collection.update({
      _id: ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")
    },
    [
      {
        $set: {
          "myarray.mysubarray": {
            $cond: [
              {
                $in: [
                  ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
                  "$myarray.mysubarray.userId"
                ]
              },
              {
                $map: {
                  input: "$myarray.mysubarray",
                  in: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        $cond: [
                          {
                            $eq: [
                              "$$this.userId",
                              ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035")
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            point: 3
                          },
                          {}
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$myarray.mysubarray",
                  [
                    {
                      userId: ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
                      point: 4
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
 db.collection.update({},
 [
 {
  "$addFields": {
  "myarray": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$myarray",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$this",
          {
            mydictionary: {
              "$objectToArray": "$$this.mydictionary"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
     }
    }
  }
  },
  // convert the nested objects to array
  {
   $addFields: {
  myarray: {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$myarray",
      "as": "m",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$m",
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$m.key",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $in: [
                      "PointB",
                      "$$m.mydictionary.k"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                k: 1,
                mydictionary: {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$$m.mydictionary",
                    "as": "md",
                    "in": {
                      "$mergeObjects": [
                        "$$md",
                        {
                          "$cond": {
                            "if": {
                              $eq: [
                                "$$md.k",
                                "PointB"
                              ]
                            },
                            "then": {
                              k:"PointB",
                              v: {
                                point: "The UPDATED element",
                                userId: "The UPDATED element"
                              }
                            },
                            "else": {}
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "else": {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$m.key",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    mydictionary: {
                      "$concatArrays": [
                        "$$m.mydictionary",
                        [
                          {
                            "k": "PointB",
                            "v": {
                              point: "The upserted element",
                              userId: "The upserted element"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "else": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
        }
      }
     }
   }
  },
 // convert back to object
 {
  "$addFields": {
   "myarray": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$myarray",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$this",
          {
            mydictionary: {
              "$arrayToObject": "$$this.mydictionary"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  }
  }
 ],
 {
  multi: true
 })
```

Explained:

1. Convert the nested mydictionary object to array
2. Update or insert the new object inside mydictionary via conditional double map/$mergeObjects
3. Convert back the nested mydictionary array to object

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C3qKvkkpnua)

Also to confirm on your question:

In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document.
For situations that require atomicity of reads and writes to multiple documents (in a single or multiple collections), MongoDB supports multi-document transaction.

[write operation atomicity](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/)

Comment: Thanks. WIll this be atomic?

Comment: atomicity in mongoDB is  guaranteed per single document  if you dont use transactions , so yes  update or upsert inside the array will be atomic , in the example I have added update/insert (multi:true ) for two documents  , the operation will not be atomic for the two documents but only per single document.

Comment: It seems to be working. What about if the item holding the points doesn't exist and we want to create it (with key: 3 for example) and holding the new point in their dictionary in the same operation? $addToSet cannot be used as far as I know because it is the same path. Tried with $addToFields but without luck

Comment: This is why I have added you 2x documents in the example collection above to ilustrate the 2x options   , in the first document it is update since PointB exists , in the second document it is upsert/addToSet  ( insert to the array = $concatAraays )  since the PointB do not exist ...

Comment: Yes, my question was more about what if the item in the myarray doesn't exist and I want to create it, but I figured out how to do it, just add an addFields extra stage for that. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Indeed you can add one more addFields stage to $concatArray:[] if key:1 is missing ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251869/discussion-between-r2d2-and-michael17).